# JobScheduler para executar a cada x horas

Tags: java, android

Estou precisando executar um acesso a api em um intervalo de horas, por exemplo a cada 3 horas.
Estava procurando modos de fazer isso, li sobre AlarmManager e sobre este JobScheduler que parece ser o mais recente.

O correto para minha finalidade é utilizar ele ?

Ele é compativel com versões anteriores do android ? ( minha versão minima é 17).

Se possível postar um exemplo de utilização dele.

Comment: Cara, o Google está cheio de ótimos tutoriais. Fiz uma pesquisa agora e o primeiro resultado que veio já é um excelente tutorial. Só precisei digitar 3 palavras na busca: job scheduler Android. Bem mais simples do que escrever toda uma pergunta.

Comment: Não consegui achar informação sobre ele funcionar em versões anteriores

Answer (score 4):

O JobScheduler requer API 21+.

Uma alternativa que funciona em todas as versões é o [GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager).

Ele usa o JobScheduler nas versões 21+ e nas versões inferiores usa uma implementação própria.

Para usá-lo, o seu serviço deve herdar de GcmTaskService.

Declare-o no AndroidManifest.xml da seguinte forma:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyTaskService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Obtenha o GcmNetworkManager:

```
mGcmNetworkManager = GcmNetworkManager.getInstance(this);
```

Agende uma tarefa periódica assim:

```
    PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask.Builder()
        .setService(MyTaskService.class)
        .setTag(TASK_TAG_PERIODIC)
        .setPeriod(30L)
        .build();

mGcmNetworkManager.schedule(task);
```

Na altura da tarefa agendada ser executada, o sistema chama o método `onRunTask()` do seu serviço.

Mais alternativas:

- [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android) que fornece uma API compatível com o JobScheduler.
  Funciona em todas as versões a partir da API 9 que têm os serviços do Google Play instalados. A retro-compatibilidade é conseguida recorrendo ao uso do GcmNetworkManager.
- [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

  Nova api incluída no novíssimo [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/).
  Usa as bibliotecas de suporte, permitindo compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

Referências:

- [Implementing GCM Network Manager on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager).

Comment: ramaral, se não me engano o job scheduler apareceu na versão 21, não 23. Eu recomendaria também o Job Scheduler do Evernote, mas ai é outro escopo :)

Comment: @Wakim obrigado. O que me induziu em erro foi que é dito em [Implementing GCM Network Manager on Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) que o GcmNetworkManager usa o JobScheduler nas versões 23+.

Comment: Estranho mesmo, ou a documentação está errada ou o Chet Haase está errado nesse post do medium: https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-iv-e7dc4ce0a59. Normal no mundo Android hehehe, nem tudo está documentado direito.