# Como deixar minha Activity em 2 plano executando uma função ?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Meu projeto é colocar uma WebView  na Activity e quando eu sair do aplicativo, **e ele ficar em 2° plano atualizando de tempos em tempos a Activity para que o site que está WebView atualiza também.**
alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Pensa comigo: Se a pessoa não estiver usando o smartphone,(por exemplo dormindo) porque ela ia querer atualizar o conteúdo de um webview?! Faz mais sentido atualizar quando o usuário abrir a aplicação. Existem algumas formas de fazer isso, porém você estará gastando recurso atoa do seu celular, como por exemplo, bateria que é um dos problemas ainda que não foram solucionados. Ainda estou esperando aquela bateria que dure 20 dias sem carregar. heuhue =D

Comment: Mas ai que ta quero que  entre num site para pegar pontos a cada 12 horas num jogo , e nesta pagina atualizado sempre ele vai pegar msm que o cara esteja dormindo a pessoa nao vai se preocupar em abrir o app para pegar os pontos.

Comment: @renansilvadasneves mas esse site então é um outro terceiro né?! Seria mais fácil alguém te ajudar se você explicar exatamente isso que está nos comentário. A probabilidade de encontrar uma resposta é maior. =D

Comment: Obrigado pela dica ;)

Comment: Relacionado(duplicata?)[JobScheduler para executar a cada x horas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/225036/2541)

Answer (score 0):

Achei um metodo eficiente para mim fazer isso, 
Jobschedeler 
Ele acorda na hora que precisa e faz sua função e desliga .